# Построение ROC кривой для задач мультиклассовой классификации

Tags: python, numpy

В моей задачи нужно найти площадь под кривой ROC для задач мультиклассовой классификации. На вход подается число объектов в выборке в первой строке и далее в каждой строке предсказанное значение и истинное.
Я пытаюсь сделать это с использованием библиотеки NumPy:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = #false positive rate
y = #true positive rate
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
auc = np.trapz(y, x)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно записать код для нахождения TPR и FPR в данной задаче без использования scikit learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TPR= TP/(TP+FN)
FPR= FP/(FP+TN)
```

А вообще-то почитайте, полезно:

https://habr.com/ru/company/ods/blog/328372/

Comment: “Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.”